# Jenkins slave configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am running a job which consist of three build steps in the master Jenkins. i.e)compile,deploy and Test script execution. I need to configure Jenkins in a way to run compile and deploy build step in master node. Test scripts needs to be executed in slave node in the same project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) or [Build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

by using these plugins you can run as many jobs with same or different slave node.

You can even run your job as sequential or parallel type.

Comment: thank you mahi. Multijob plugin works for me to handle this

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to launch your tests with a downstream job.

If you need to pass some parameters from the current job, you can use the [jenkins parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).